# Packer.io: Tag or Label VMWare instances (app/inventory management)

Tags: vmware, packer

Using Packer.io, is there a way to 'tag' or 'label', similar to AWS, but with the VMWare builder or vsphere post-processor and have that tag/label show up in vSphere?

i.e. tag an image with 'appType=Database' when building the vmware image and after loading into vsphere have it visible in vsphere?

thanks!
-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packer don't support the vSphere API, just building natively on ESXi and I believe tags are a vSphere feature, unless it's part of the `vmx` file, but I couldn't find any references  of tags [here](http://sanbarrow.com/vmx.html).

You can verify if it's saved in the `vmx` file by adding a tag to a VM and open the `vmx` file and check if it contains your tag.

Comment: This seems consistent in that there is *not* a way to support this, thanks for the double-check